# Error while rebuilding PHP 7 to add ODBC extension MacOS 10.13 (High Sierra): Makefile is not as expected

Tags: php, macos, codeigniter, odbc, filemaker

I'm currently struggling with an issue with ODBC. 
I need to use odbc to connect with a FileMaker database.

I've set up a VM with MacOS High Sierra + Apache + MySQL + Php7 and I've already installed ODBC Manager (from ActualTech) + FileMaker ODBC driver.

My web-app is a copy from a previous project hosted on a MacOS 10.8.
On MacOS 10.8 everything goes fine. But on new High Sierra I get this error

> Call to undefined function odbc_connect()

I'm using CodeIgniter as PhP framework, but I think error may be related to PhP version since it looks like PhP does not recognize this method as its own.

I've read on PhP official web site that [odbc_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php) is fully compatible with PHP v7.

Even though, I cannot figure out why I get this error.

Is it related to new MacOS versions (it seems it has been removed ODBC Support on earlier OSX, as you can read [here](https://community.intersystems.com/post/using-odbc-php-os-x-109-mavericks))?

Plus, I found out some articles that suggest to re-build PHP from source, adding this ODBC support manually. Should I go this way? I'm not fully sure I can go with this solution.

**UPDATE (I'm rebuilding PHP from source)**

I e-mailed to acutaltech support and they suggested me to follow instructions here http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/IODBCPHPHOWTOMacOSX. So I'm trying to compile and build PHP on my own, but my Makefile does not contain anything about ODBC.

This is my Makefile

```
mkinstalldirs = $(top_srcdir)/build/shtool mkdir -p
INSTALL = $(top_srcdir)/build/shtool install -c
INSTALL_DATA = $(INSTALL) -m 644

DEFS = -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I$(top_builddir)/include -I$(top_builddir)/main -I$(top_srcdir)
COMMON_FLAGS = $(DEFS) $(INCLUDES) $(EXTRA_INCLUDES) $(CPPFLAGS) $(PHP_FRAMEWORKPATH)

all: $(all_targets)
    @echo
    @echo "Build complete."
    @echo "Don't forget to run 'make test'."
    @echo

build-modules: $(PHP_MODULES) $(PHP_ZEND_EX)

build-binaries: $(PHP_BINARIES)

libphp$(PHP_MAJOR_VERSION).la: $(PHP_GLOBAL_OBJS) $(PHP_SAPI_OBJS)
    $(LIBTOOL) --mode=link $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS) -rpath $(phptempdir) $(EXTRA_LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(PHP_RPATHS) $(PHP_GLOBAL_OBJS) $(PHP_SAPI_OBJS) $(EXTRA_LIBS) $(ZEND_EXTRA_LIBS) -o $@
    -@$(LIBTOOL) --silent --mode=install cp $@ $(phptempdir)/$@ >/dev/null 2>&1

libs/libphp$(PHP_MAJOR_VERSION).bundle: $(PHP_GLOBAL_OBJS) $(PHP_SAPI_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(MH_BUNDLE_FLAGS) $(CFLAGS_CLEAN) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(EXTRA_LDFLAGS) $(PHP_GLOBAL_OBJS:.lo=.o) $(PHP_SAPI_OBJS:.lo=.o) $(PHP_FRAMEWORKS) $(EXTRA_LIBS) $(ZEND_EXTRA_LIBS) -o $@ && cp $@ libs/libphp$(PHP_MAJOR_VERSION).so

install: $(all_targets) $(install_targets)

install-sapi: $(OVERALL_TARGET)
    @echo "Installing PHP SAPI module:       $(PHP_SAPI)"
    -@$(mkinstalldirs) $(INSTALL_ROOT)$(bindir)
    -@if test ! -r $(phptempdir)/libphp$(PHP_MAJOR_VERSION).$(SHLIB_DL_SUFFIX_NAME); then \
        for i in 0.0.0 0.0 0; do \
            if test -r $(phptempdir)/libphp$(PHP_MAJOR_VERSION).$(SHLIB_DL_SUFFIX_NAME).$$i; then \
                $(LN_S) $(phptempdir)/libphp$(PHP_MAJOR_VERSION).$(SHLIB_DL_SUFFIX_NAME).$$i $(phptempdir)/libphp$(PHP_MAJOR_VERSION).$(SHLIB_DL_SUFFIX_NAME); \
                break; \
            fi; \
        done; \
    fi
    @$(INSTALL_IT)

install-binaries: build-binaries $(install_binary_targets)

install-modules: build-modules
    @test -d modules && \
    $(mkinstalldirs) $(INSTALL_ROOT)$(EXTENSION_DIR)
    @echo "Installing shared extensions:     $(INSTALL_ROOT)$(EXTENSION_DIR)/"
    @rm -f modules/*.la >/dev/null 2>&1
    @$(INSTALL) modules/* $(INSTALL_ROOT)$(EXTENSION_DIR)

install-headers:
    -@if test "$(INSTALL_HEADERS)"; then \
        for i in `echo $(INSTALL_HEADERS)`; do \
            i=`$(top_srcdir)/build/shtool path -d $$i`; \
            paths="$$paths $(INSTALL_ROOT)$(phpincludedir)/$$i"; \
        done; \
        $(mkinstalldirs) $$paths && \
        echo "Installing header files:          $(INSTALL_ROOT)$(phpincludedir)/" && \
        for i in `echo $(INSTALL_HEADERS)`; do \
            if test "$(PHP_PECL_EXTENSION)"; then \
                src=`echo $$i | $(SED) -e "s#ext/$(PHP_PECL_EXTENSION)/##g"`; \
            else \
                src=$$i; \
            fi; \
            if test -f "$(top_srcdir)/$$src"; then \
                $(INSTALL_DATA) $(top_srcdir)/$$src $(INSTALL_ROOT)$(phpincludedir)/$$i; \
            elif test -f "$(top_builddir)/$$src"; then \
                $(INSTALL_DATA) $(top_builddir)/$$src $(INSTALL_ROOT)$(phpincludedir)/$$i; \
            else \
                (cd $(top_srcdir)/$$src && $(INSTALL_DATA) *.h $(INSTALL_ROOT)$(phpincludedir)/$$i; \
                cd $(top_builddir)/$$src && $(INSTALL_DATA) *.h $(INSTALL_ROOT)$(phpincludedir)/$$i) 2>/dev/null || true; \
            fi \
        done; \
    fi

PHP_TEST_SETTINGS = -d 'open_basedir=' -d 'output_buffering=0' -d 'memory_limit=-1'
PHP_TEST_SHARED_EXTENSIONS =  ` \
    if test "x$(PHP_MODULES)" != "x"; then \
        for i in $(PHP_MODULES)""; do \
            . $$i; $(top_srcdir)/build/shtool echo -n -- " -d extension=$$dlname"; \
        done; \
    fi; \
    if test "x$(PHP_ZEND_EX)" != "x"; then \
        for i in $(PHP_ZEND_EX)""; do \
            . $$i; $(top_srcdir)/build/shtool echo -n -- " -d $(ZEND_EXT_TYPE)=$(top_builddir)/modules/$$dlname"; \
        done; \
    fi`
PHP_DEPRECATED_DIRECTIVES_REGEX = '^(magic_quotes_(gpc|runtime|sybase)?|(zend_)?extension(_debug)?(_ts)?)[\t\ ]*='

test: all
    @if test ! -z "$(PHP_EXECUTABLE)" && test -x "$(PHP_EXECUTABLE)"; then \
        INI_FILE=`$(PHP_EXECUTABLE) -d 'display_errors=stderr' -r 'echo php_ini_loaded_file();' 2> /dev/null`; \
        if test "$$INI_FILE"; then \
            $(EGREP) -h -v $(PHP_DEPRECATED_DIRECTIVES_REGEX) "$$INI_FILE" > $(top_builddir)/tmp-php.ini; \
        else \
            echo > $(top_builddir)/tmp-php.ini; \
        fi; \
        INI_SCANNED_PATH=`$(PHP_EXECUTABLE) -d 'display_errors=stderr' -r '$$a = explode(",\n", trim(php_ini_scanned_files())); echo $$a[0];' 2> /dev/null`; \
        if test "$$INI_SCANNED_PATH"; then \
            INI_SCANNED_PATH=`$(top_srcdir)/build/shtool path -d $$INI_SCANNED_PATH`; \
            $(EGREP) -h -v $(PHP_DEPRECATED_DIRECTIVES_REGEX) "$$INI_SCANNED_PATH"/*.ini >> $(top_builddir)/tmp-php.ini; \
        fi; \
        TEST_PHP_EXECUTABLE=$(PHP_EXECUTABLE) \
        TEST_PHP_SRCDIR=$(top_srcdir) \
        CC="$(CC)" \
            $(PHP_EXECUTABLE) -n -c $(top_builddir)/tmp-php.ini $(PHP_TEST_SETTINGS) $(top_srcdir)/run-tests.php -n -c $(top_builddir)/tmp-php.ini -d extension_dir=$(top_builddir)/modules/ $(PHP_TEST_SHARED_EXTENSIONS) $(TESTS); \
        TEST_RESULT_EXIT_CODE=$$?; \
        rm $(top_builddir)/tmp-php.ini; \
        exit $$TEST_RESULT_EXIT_CODE; \
    else \
        echo "ERROR: Cannot run tests without CLI sapi."; \
    fi

clean:
    find . -name \*.gcno -o -name \*.gcda | xargs rm -f
    find . -name \*.lo -o -name \*.o | xargs rm -f
    find . -name \*.la -o -name \*.a | xargs rm -f
    find . -name \*.so | xargs rm -f
    find . -name .libs -a -type d|xargs rm -rf
    rm -f libphp$(PHP_MAJOR_VERSION).la $(SAPI_CLI_PATH) $(SAPI_CGI_PATH) $(SAPI_MILTER_PATH) $(SAPI_LITESPEED_PATH) $(SAPI_FPM_PATH) $(OVERALL_TARGET) modules/* libs/*

distclean: clean
    rm -f Makefile config.cache config.log config.status Makefile.objects Makefile.fragments libtool main/php_config.h main/internal_functions_cli.c main/internal_functions.c stamp-h buildmk.stamp Zend/zend_dtrace_gen.h Zend/zend_dtrace_gen.h.bak Zend/zend_config.h TSRM/tsrm_config.h
    rm -f php7.spec main/build-defs.h scripts/phpize
    rm -f ext/date/lib/timelib_config.h ext/mbstring/oniguruma/config.h ext/mbstring/libmbfl/config.h ext/oci8/oci8_dtrace_gen.h ext/oci8/oci8_dtrace_gen.h.bak
    rm -f scripts/man1/phpize.1 scripts/php-config scripts/man1/php-config.1 sapi/cli/php.1 sapi/cgi/php-cgi.1 ext/phar/phar.1 ext/phar/phar.phar.1
    rm -f sapi/fpm/php-fpm.conf sapi/fpm/init.d.php-fpm sapi/fpm/php-fpm.service sapi/fpm/php-fpm.8 sapi/fpm/status.html
    rm -f ext/iconv/php_have_bsd_iconv.h ext/iconv/php_have_glibc_iconv.h ext/iconv/php_have_ibm_iconv.h ext/iconv/php_have_iconv.h ext/iconv/php_have_libiconv.h ext/iconv/php_iconv_aliased_libiconv.h ext/iconv/php_iconv_supports_errno.h ext/iconv/php_php_iconv_h_path.h ext/iconv/php_php_iconv_impl.h
    rm -f ext/phar/phar.phar ext/phar/phar.php
    if test "$(srcdir)" != "$(builddir)"; then \
      rm -f ext/phar/phar/phar.inc; \
    fi
    $(EGREP) define'.*include/php' $(top_srcdir)/configure | $(SED) 's/.*>//'|xargs rm -f

prof-gen:
    CCACHE_DISABLE=1 $(MAKE) PROF_FLAGS=-fprofile-generate all

prof-clean:
    find . -name \*.lo -o -name \*.o | xargs rm -f
    find . -name \*.la -o -name \*.a | xargs rm -f
    find . -name \*.so | xargs rm -f
    rm -f libphp$(PHP_MAJOR_VERSION).la $(SAPI_CLI_PATH) $(SAPI_CGI_PATH) $(SAPI_MILTER_PATH) $(SAPI_LITESPEED_PATH) $(SAPI_FPM_PATH) $(OVERALL_TARGET) modules/* libs/*

prof-use:
    CCACHE_DISABLE=1 $(MAKE) PROF_FLAGS=-fprofile-use all


.PHONY: all clean install distclean test prof-gen prof-clean prof-use
.NOEXPORT:
```

Now I'm really confused. How can I add the ODBC extension to my PHP build?

**UPDATE 2 (How I solved this issue)**

I could not build my own PHP version with ODBC. To everyone having this issue I solved by using PHP-OSX, that's basically a PHP version customized with all extensions needed, already built. You can download the binary file here https://php-osx.liip.ch.

Hope this helps!

Comment: FileMaker Server installation comes with it's own php install, which is php 5. It sounds like you use that instead of your custom install. Just confirm with php.ini what are you using. Also, did you set up DSN for the database in the new vm and do you have a user with ODBC privilege enabled?

Comment: Hi @NicolaiKant thanks for your answer. Actually FMServer is installed on another Mac. The main problem is that I cannot see odbc as a php extension, seems like php doesn't include this. I found out that others are having this issue and looks it's related to the PHP build. I'm trying to compile and build PHP by myself with iodbc configuration, but I can't edit the Makefile as suggested here http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/IODBCPHPHOWTOMacOSX. My Makefile doesn't have lines for ODBC!

Comment: I updated my answer to explain better my new issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

I could not build my own PHP version with ODBC. To everyone having this issue I solved by using PHP-OSX, that's basically a PHP version customized with all extensions needed, already built. You can download the binary file here https://php-osx.liip.ch.

Hope this helps!